# R: I want to paste together values of 31 character variables without explicitly referring to each variable name

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a new variable in a dataframe in R, which will be a concatenation of the values of 31 character variables, but I don't want to explicitly refer to each of these variables by name, can anyone help me with this?

More specifically:

My dataframe is called 'TVs', with 35 variables, and I want to paste the values of character variables 2 to variable 31, which are all character variables.

I can do this for the first two variables with the following:

```
TVs2 <- TVs %>%
  mutate(productid = paste0(BRAND,`COMMON INTER CI`))
```

and that works, but I don't want to explicitly type in the 31 variable names, so instead I've created a list of the variables I want as follows:

```
names <- names(TVs)
names2 <- names[-c(1,32,33,34)]
```

and then I tried

```
TVs2 <- TVs %>%
  mutate(productid = str_c(unlist(names2)))
```

which gave me this error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `productid`.
ℹ `productid = str_c(unlist(names2))`.
ℹ `productid` must be size 7521 or 1, not 30.
```

Can anybody help me out please?

Comment: `TVs$productid <- do.call(paste0, TVs[2:31])`

Comment: A `tidyverse` approach 

`TVs %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(productid = str_c(c_across(-id),collapse = ","))`

Comment: @ViníciusFélix - I'm presuming that runs `str_c` for every row, which will slow down markedly on large datasets. Probably better to use a vectorised function like: `mtcars %>% unite(productid, -mpg, sep=",")` as shown at the duplicate.